container ldd different results on different hosts
Running the same Docker container on different hosts we are seeing some run-time undefined symbol lookups. We can fix these with -rpath, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, link order, etc, but first we are trying to understand what ldd is doing. We see slight differences in ldd output, for example:
Host A
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.15) 2.31
...

Host B
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
...

I know containers share Linux kernels with their host, but I thought the GLIBC filesystem would not vary. Is ldd making some kernel syscalls that come back with different results ? If the undefined symbol is a vector math function (AVX) could the underlying CPU type have any effect ?

I'll be bold, and say that your logic is sound. Following that, because the result is a contradiction, your assumptions must be false. I guess, you are not running the same docker containers.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  How are you building the image, are you literally running the same image on both systems (for example, pushed to a registry and pulled, not rebuilt), how exactly are you running ldd?

my initial thought also - possibly something was done to the container after it was downloaded. But testers say not. I will gather md5 sums for the containers after download, then immediately upon running them check ldd output again

@DavidMaze yes pulled from a registry (not rebuilt), then run the container, then run ldd --version. Host A is not under my control, but I'll get the container md5 info and re-verify ldd output

we've not been able to reproduce this, not for lack of trying. Should I delete the question ?
